# Fail to redirect log to /var/log/syslog

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, root, upstart

I have an [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) script that does the following

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

respawn

pre-start script
    exec >/dev/kmsg 2>&1
    REPO=git@github.com:blabla/bli
    mkdir -p /var/log
    mkdir -p /var/www
    echo "Fetching app from $REPO"
    girror $REPO /var/www
    if [ -f /var/www/package.json ]; then
        echo "Installing npm modules"
        cd /var/www
        npm install
    fi
end script

post-stop script
    exec >/dev/kmsg 2>&1
    echo "stopped"
end script

script
    exec >/dev/kmsg 2>&1
    export NODE_ENV=production
    export port=80
    echo "Starting app.js on port 80"
    cd /var/www
    node app.js
end script
```

I am running the script as root. The log files of the application suppose to go to `/var/log/syslog` but they don't go there.

However, I do see the app log when running `dmesg | tail -f`

Using kernel `3.5.0-46`

Anyone know why it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because your script explicitly *redirects* all output to dmesg:

```
exec >/dev/kmsg 2>&1
```

Comment: I have the exact script running on a different ubuntu machine on AWS and it is redirecting okay.

Comment: @Michael: What kernel version is it running?

Comment: the problematic one is running `3.5.0-46-generic #70~precise1-Ubuntu` the one that works is running `3.2.0-31-virtual #50-Ubuntu`

Comment: is it possible that on the working machine, all dmesg input is also redirected to `/var/log/syslog` ? btw, I am usually using `rsyslog` to send the log to a remote machine, it always mirrors what I have in `/var/log/www` to the remote machine like this

Comment: @Michael: No. Rather, on the working machine, there is no dmesg input _at all_. Kernels before 3.5 **did not have a writable `/dev/kmsg`** device, so the `exec` line fails, the script ignores errors, and simply continues logging to where it was redirected previously (by Upstart).

Comment: but the working machine is the one with the older kernel, so how come it is able to write to `/dev/kmsg` successfully ? isn't it suppose to be the opposite ?

Comment: @Michael: Your original question does say the opposite – you wrote that it does *not* work because logs go to dmesg and not syslog.

Comment: is there any way I can redirect it as I want in the newer kernel ?

Comment: @Michael: By removing the `exec >/dev/kmsg` lines?

Comment: removing the lines and restarting did not work :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13402/discussion-between-michael-and-grawity)