# error with upstart script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pipe, upstart

Further to [my last question](https://superuser.com/questions/725256/), I'm now using `logger`.

I have the following upstart configuration

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

respawn

pre-start script
    exec 2>&1 > >(logger -t "nodejs")
    REPO=git@github.com
    mkdir -p /var/log
    mkdir -p /var/www
    echo "Fetching app from $REPO"
    girror $REPO /var/www
    if [ -f /var/www/package.json ]; then
        echo "Installing npm modules"
        cd /var/www
        npm install
    fi
end script

post-stop script
    exec 2>&1 > >(logger -t "nodejs")
    echo "stopped"
end script

script
    exec 2>&1 > >(logger -t "nodejs")
    export NODE_ENV=production
    export port=80
    echo "Starting app.js on port 80"
    cd /var/www
    node app.js
end script
```

I am getting the error

```
/proc/self/fd/9: 2: /proc/self/fd/9: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

I suspect it's the line

```
exec 2>&1 > >(logger -t "nodejs")
```

Although it was working when I ran it in a normal shell script.

You know whats wrong ?

Comment: Is the script being executed using `sh`?  If so, you might expect errors.  Execute the script using `bash`.

Comment: @devnull I'm not sure how upstart is executing it's scripts. Can I force it to use bash in any way ? I see that `/bin/sh` is actuallt pointing to `dash`